How to transform data in the production database using C# code?
I have a question about transforming data on the database using C# code. I'm familiar with using migrations in ASP.NET with EF Core to modify the database schema and running raw SQL commands during migration to transform data.
However, my current requirement is a bit more complex, and I cannot make the necessary data changes using raw SQL.
Here's the situation: I have a table called Homes with a column named Description. In my migration, I want to:

Add a new column called PublicDescription.

Set the value of PublicDescription to RedactSensitiveInfo(Description) for all rows, where RedactSensitiveInfo is a C# method that sanitizes the Description content.


The challenge I'm facing is that I need to run C# code to perform this data transformation and therefore cannot use a raw SQL command. During a migration, I don't have direct access to a DbContext to execute such changes, so I feel stuck.
Has anyone tackled a similar problem or have any suggestions on how to approach this?
Thanks in advance!

Create a console app that would pull records from db and update them using the c# method

Is the RedactSensitiveInfo function actually automatic... or not? i.e. is this an offline process, or will you be given a figurative spreadsheet with all of the corrected text all ready for you?

If this is a SQL Server instance that you (or your org) controls, then you can use SQLCLR to run .NET Fx 4.x assemblies just like a normal T-SQL function - though there are caveats (e.g. no external IO, of course), but if your RedactSensitiveInfo is basically just a bunch of regeexes than that might be an option.

Do you actually need to store the redacted information in your database at all? If you have the full description in your database, can you not just run the description through your C# transformation method on retrieval? The PublicDescription would then be a computer property on the entity.
public string PublicDescription { get; } => RedactSensitiveInfo(Description)

@anaotha you haven’t answered my questions

Why can't you add the column first (by migrations) and populate it later?

you could try modifying the generated migration file to add new Column

How do you execute you migrations - is it in different host or just on startup ?

seems like you want a migration and then create a seed function.  That'll take care of existing data.  For new data you'd do the processing when adding.
